# C program errors on print

Tags: c, console-application

I'm extremely new to C programming and I'm writing a basic code that collects first and last name, hours worked, hourly wage, and then returns the last name, first name, and the hours * wage:

```
    char first_name;
    char last_name;

    printf("\n%s, %s: %.2lf\n", last_name, first_name, total_payment);
```

The error I receive while compiling is:

```
payroll.c:22:13: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type char *' but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
printf("\n%s, %s: %.2lf\n", last_name, first_name, total_payment);
          ^

payroll.c:22:13: warning: format '%s' expects argument of type char *' but argument 3 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]
printf("\n%s, %s: %.2lf\n", last_name, first_name, total_payment);
              ^
```

I don't understand the error. Is `char *` a pointer? Why doesn't it return the first char variable listed, then the second, before a .2 floating point int? I'm also using nano so it's impossible to debug as I normally would. (A recommended IDE would also be extremely helpful.)

Comment: `first_name` and `last_name` are *single characters*. They can't hold null-terminated byte strings. It seems you could need to take a step back with your book or tutorial.

Comment: `%s` is for a string. You pass asingle character. A single character is not a string. A string has a zero characte as terminator.

Comment: The free Visual Studio edition is good for debugging and imo generally a pleasant IDE if you are on Windows. Maybe somebody recommend IDEs for Linux and Mac?

Comment: Got a point from me for reading and considering compiler warnings. That's more than even many experienced programmers can bring themselves to do.

Comment: Thank you, everyone. I'm coming from Java so this is super unfamiliar in some respects. I appreciate the help and did solve the problem with the suggestions plus my resources. (Normally it takes me hours or days but this was instant.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've declared your `first_name` and `last_name` variables as `char` datatype. They should be declared as `char*` and allocate memory or declare it as `char[]` of required size.

Also change your scanf statements to remove the `&` while capturing the user input to variable as these variables already hold the address.

Comment: That's not enough, unless the OP makes them point somewhere valid (which you don't describe how to do). Considering the confusion of the OP this might even be pretty bad advice.

Comment: This was enough, plus my resources, to solve the problem. Thank you for taking the time. This was literally my first program and I'm just beginning to understand malloc, which is hard. Much appreciation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem starts already at `scanf`.

With a `%s` conversion it will read a "word" from the input; more exactly, it will read characters until it hits a whitespace (which is put back into the input). These characters are copied to the memory starting at the location which you provided; at the end, `scanf` will add a null character in order to terminate the C string it created.

In your case, you provided a location which holds only a single character. `scanf` does not know that and will continue to write into the memory beyond that single character, overwriting other data and infrastructure information of your program, with disastrous effects.

As others have said, you must provide more space in memory for the names. Typically one would declare character arrays, like `char first_name[200];`, here containing space for 200 characters.<sup>1</sup>

Technically, `first_name[200]` declares an array, not a character pointer; but in all common uses the language adjusts it to a pointer containing the address of the first character in the array, which is exactly what `scanf`(and `printf`) expect. And both of them expect that the address points to an array which has enough space (in case of `scanf`) respectively contains a null-terminated sequence of characters (in the case of `printf`).

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> One should make sure not to read longer input (and make `scanf` overwrite unrelated memory again)  by using a field length for the conversion. In our case `scanf("%199s", first_name);` would indicate that we read a maximum of 199 characters from the input, leaving the last byte in the array for the terminating zero character which `scanf` will silently add.</sub>

<sub>The rest of a very long name would stay in the input queue and be read as the next string, leading to an error, but handling input errors in a fool-proof manner is non-trivial. Which is sad because beginner programs often are centered around human input. "Normal" programs, by contrast, prompt for user input very rarely — with the notable exceptions of your shell and your editor.</sub>